# Greek Letters without Bold

Tags: symbols, bold, greek

While using Greek symbols within a math environment, such as an equation, they are normally printed as bold. However, I would like it to be printed without bold. There are many questions asking how to put the greek symbols in bold, but none I could find that says how to "unbold" the symbol when displaying?

Please point me to a question that answers this if I have not been thorough.

```
\begin{equation}

    \label{eq:cov1}

    R_\mathbf{v}=E\left \{ \mathbf{vv}^H \right \} = \text{\textsigma}_{\mathbf{v}} ^2 \mathbf{I}

\end{equation}
```

Comment: They would not normally be printed bold. Please make your code into a full but minimal example, so others can copy and test. I also wonder why you are using text symbols in math

Comment: Do you actually have blank lines in your equation?  And why do you use `\text{\textsigma}` instead of `\sigma`?

Comment: Generally, all greek letters are never print in Bold face, unless you give any tags or some special style files used....Please provide MWE of what you tried, for other's better understanding...